# Вызов подметода плагина jQuery

Tags: jquery, вёрстка, javascript

Пишу свой [мини плагин](http://jsfiddle.net/RtLWR/). В принципе, сейчас все работает так, как мне надо, но я сомневаюсь, что правильно сделал рекурсию:

```
settings.container.lieffect().liHide(item);
```

Ведь в этом случае, фактически, создается новый объект, а это по-моему расточительно и не совсем правильно. Объект уже имеется, просто нужно вызвать его соответствующий подметод, а я что-то не соображу, как это сделать. Есть ли другие варианты вызова подметода в моем случае? Так же буду рад услышать любую другую критику по поводу этого недокода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас шаблон неправильный, обычно методы в плагинах вешаются не на сам объект а на [опции плагина](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/RtLWR/4/) (посмотрите как вызываются методы в jquery-ui). можно сделать так: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/RtLWR/2/ но это немного странно (как раз из-за того, что методы (`this.liHide, this.liShow`) присваиваются при каждом вызове плагина)

Обратите так-же внимание, что у вас очень сильное дублирование кода, представьте что методов подобных будет больше 3х.

Comment: >> У вас шаблон неправильный, обычно методы в плагинах вешаются не 
>> на сам объект а на опции плагина

Да, косяк, шаблон выбрал из первой попавшейся статьи, т.к. до этого написал своих плагинов один с половиной и не имею опыта в выборе структуры плагина. К сожалению, ui слишком объёмен - неудобно эти примеры воспринимать целиком. Дело еще в том, что время достаточно ограничено - было бы больше, думаю, добрался бы и до него.

Comment: да не надо внутри копаться, просто посмотрите чего плагины ui хотят, и подумайте почему, в общем-то примерно я реализовал в ответе :) а good practice по плагинописательству [полно](http://habrahabr.ru/post/158235/#comment_5446679) в инете